# Destructuring nested object with same named property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I have the following object:

```
const randomObject = {
  propertyA: someValueA,
  propertyB: someValueB,
  nestedObj:{
    propertyA: someOtherValueA,
    propertyX: someValueX
  }
};
```

Now if I destructure the randomObject using `const{propertyA} = randomObject` then I get the value someValueA but I want the propertyA to be someOtherValueA from nestedObject inside randomObject. The other answers on StackOverflow have a different name of the property in the child object and not the exact same parent-child name.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: const {nestedObj : {propertyA}} = randomObject;

Comment: https://puu.sh/EaU0A/b63d236efc.png